# Should I configure caching before uploading to server in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Before I upload my Laravel project to the server I clean all caches on my localhost instance.

```
config:clear
view:clear
route:clear
config:clear
optimize:clear
```

I can not run artisan command on the server because the it doesn't support it.

In php artisan, there are some commands:

```
config:cache
view:cache
route:cache
config:cache
```

Should I run them in localhost (before uploading) or will it generate automatically by Laravel on the server?

Comment: delete storage/framework/* folder and upload it on the server. I think you will be good to go

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying your site to a server you shouldn't upload any files that are in folders that are defined in Laravel's gitignore files. If you are doing this running those commands before deploying does not matter.

I don't recommend running a Laravel project on a server that you do not have SSH access to, but if you really have to you can call Artisan commands from PHP code like:

`Artisan::call('config:clear');`